# Learning Python - len() returns 2n+2

Tags: python, string-length

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate post but search seemed to yield no useful results...or maybe I'm such a noob that I'm not understanding what is being said in the answers.

I wrote this small code for practice (following "learning Python the hard way"). I tried to make a shorter version of a code which was already given to me.

```
from sys import argv

script, from_file, to_file = argv

# here is the part where I tried to simplify the commands and see if I still get the same result,
# Turns out it's the same 2n+2
trial = open(from_file)
trial_data = trial.read()
print(len(trial_data))
trial.close()

# actual code after defining the argumentative variables
in_file = open(from_file).read()

input(f"Transfering {len(in_file)} characters from {from_file} to {to_file}, hit RETURN to continue, CRTL-C to abort.")
#'in_data = in_file.read()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w').write(in_file)
```

When using len() it always seems to return 2n+2 value instead of n, where n is the actual number of characters in the text file. I also made sure there are no extra lines in the text file.

Can someone kindly explain?

TIA

I was expecting the exact number of characters found in the txt file to be returned. Turns out it's too much to ask.

Edit: since so many are asking for a practical example....here it goes:

```
The poem 
dedicated to Puxijn
The Chonk one
```

What i get is

```
ÿþT h e   p o e m

 d e d i c a t e d   t o   P u x i j n

 T h e   C h o n k   o n e
```

I think it is an encoding problem. I'm using the latest python if that is of any help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior, so I have several followup questions: does the file contain more complex characters (e.g. unicode smiles) or can it fully be read using ASCII encoding?
How did you create and edit the file, which charset is your editor using?

To me it seems like a weird encode with 2-byte characters (and one unintended newline) leading to 2n + 2 characters once read in python.

Comment: @LorenzHetterich why do you think `len(some_string)` would treat a two-byte character differently than any other character? It is working with *unicode code points*.

Comment: Outputs of `print(repr(in_file))` and `print(list(map(ord, in_file)))`?

Comment: "When using len() it always seems to return 2n+2 value instead of n, where n is the actual number of characters in the text file. " No, the *atual number of characters* is what `len` returns. If you think this is different, then almost certainly, your expectation of the number of characters is wrong. I am inclined to trust the python interpreter here. "I was expecting the exact number of characters found in the txt file to be returned. Turns out it's too much to ask." You are getting what you are asking for.

Comment: Psychic debugging: I strongly suspect this is not your actual code, and that you're seeing 2n+2 when you *write* a file in text mode using `'utf-16'` encoding, but check the size in some other way (e.g. reading from it in binary mode). For data where all the characters are part of the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), and you don't specify endianness, a `str` with length `n` encoded to `'utf-16'` would produce 2n + 2 bytes (2n for the actual data, the extra 2 for the BOM it gets prefixed with to indicate endianness).

Comment: @ShadowRanger something like this would be what I would suspect, but given the code above, `len` would not behave that way. It would give you the number of unicode code points in the `str` object.

Comment: In any case, you really must provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you're on a UNIX-like system, try running (at a command line, not in Python) `file path/to/from_file`, and confirm that you're not passing `'rb'` as the mode when opening it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Yeah. My suspicion is this is not really their code, and they oversimplified to the point where it no longer reproduces the problem.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is true for sane charsets. However, use some weird charset that e.g. uses `0x0A0A` as a single character, while it would be two whitespace in unicode and the length will not match.

Comment: @LorenzHetterich sorry, can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: see https://edube.org/sandbox/22463ca8-6531-11ed-a1eb-0242157e55ca as example.
By default, `open` uses `utf8` as charset. However, if the file is written with an incompatible charset (here `utf16`), the length doesn't match after reading.

Comment: @everyone I elaborated with an edit.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think you are on the right track, but I don't know how the fix this mess. Please refer to the post, I have added an example of what is going on.

Comment: @MisterMace: Yeah, you're reading UTF-16 encoded text using the `latin-1` or `cp1252` codec. Change all your `open` calls to add an extra argument, `encoding='utf-16'`, and things should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, you're definitely reading from UTF-16 encoded text files using the locale default encoding (probably `latin-1` or `cp1252`, both of which would decode the UTF-16 BOM to `ÿþ`; Windows often uses `cp1252` as the default, and `latin-1`, while largely eclipsed by UTF-8 in the present day, was a popular locale on older UNIX-likes for a long time). Those encodings will read any old bytes without error, even if the encoding is wrong (they map one to one from all 256 bytes to a matching 256 characters), producing gibberish (for bytes outside the ASCII range), and weird gaps (for the null bytes before each ASCII character in UTF-16).

Change all your `open` calls to add an extra argument, `encoding='utf-16'`, e.g.:

```
trial = open(from_file, encoding='utf-16')
```

and Python will use the correct text encoding to decode the raw bytes to a `str`, and all your lengths will match up.

Alternatively, when saving the files in a reasonable editor, make sure to tweak the encoding to make it an encoding Python will use by default (in modern Python, [you can force UTF-8 mode](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-540-forced-utf-8-runtime-mode) regardless of locale settings, and UTF-8 is probably the most popular portable encoding, in part because for pure ASCII text, it's identical to ASCII, wasting no disk space).

Comment: Thank you, your answer is really helpful. I created my txt files through powershell which might give a different encoding to the file. I'll try using my text editor which shows the encoding used. I'm still confused on how to use the 'encoding' command as I sometimes am using other commands to read a txt file, such as 
```
def print_all(f):
    print(f.read())
```
but I will figure it out as I go along.

Thanks again for your time :)

Answer (score -2):

Possibly the extra characters are the new line character or some other invisible to-your-text-editor character?

Try to make a simple test file with only one character.
eg run

```
echo "a" > test_file
```

Also there is a dedicated bash command to count such stuff

```
wc -m
```

Comment: I created a file through echo and after copying through my small program it seems to have a special character. But I truly can't understand were it is coming from.

I typed this in my terminal: echo "mark" > text.txt

and got this: mark਍ഀ

Comment: What terminal client are you using to see the file content? What is the text encoding?  also what is the output of wc -m text.txt ?

Comment: @MisterMace Why not do the prints that I requested, which would let us know those special characters?

Answer (score -4):

The observed behaviour is consistent with opening the file in binary mode and the file being encoded in utf-16 with a BOM.

If you then call `len` on the contents of that file it will count the bytes in that file.
The amount of bytes will depend on the specific encoding.

That would explain both the `2n` cause every utf-16 char has 2 bytes as well as the `+ 2` the BOM newline.

Comment: This would only be true if you open the file in binary mode. Otherwise it's parsed according to the appropriate encoding.

Comment: "If you call len on the contents of a file it will count the bytes in that file. The amount of bytes will depend on the encoding." no, that is not how `str` objects work, which is what `in_file = open(from_file).read()` gives you

Comment: My bad, I based my answer on https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_read.asp which states `.read()` returns bytes.

Comment: @cafce25 stop using w3schools. it is a notoriously bad resource. `.read` returns a `str` or `bytes` depending on the mode the file is opened in (text vs binary)